# Android Studio Response Listener

Tags: android, json

I keep getting this java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error
I'm having trouble on the jsonResponse and my friend have no problem running the application on emulator with the same code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String email = jsonResponse.getString("email");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);

                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }

            };
            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password,responseListener );
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and here are the errors

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
at chengweifeng1132701116.fyp.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:50)
at chengweifeng1132701116.fyp.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:46)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the response you get from server.Because the response you are getting have something with html tags 
 which is not a JSON response...

Comment: there's some problem in my php file and i've fixed it.. thanks for the help ! cheers !